# How to find words in a list of strings using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am trying to output a list of every word that is in a list of strings. This following code works BUT it doesn't catch 'i' as a word? I really struggle with regex, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
example = ["hi one don't 42 i i",'hello world','foo bar i']

word_list = []
for words in list(example):
    rgx = re.compile("([\w][\w']*\w)")
    word_list += rgx.findall(words)
word_list
```

output

```
['hi', 'one', "don't", '42', 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Try `\b(\w+(?:[']\w+)*)\b` but is more complxated thin that

Comment: @Edward didn't seem to work, thanks for trying though!

Comment: I try but work. thinks anywha.
>>> print ( re.compile(r"\b(\w+(?:[']\w+)*)\b").findall("hi one don't 42 i i hello world foo bar i") )
`['hi', 'one', "don't", '42', 'i', 'i', 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'i']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *all* the words in all of the sentences, you can just use a nested list comprehension, finding all the words in each sentence in the list using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
example = ["hi one don't 42 i i",'hello world','foo bar i']
words = [word for sentence in example for word in sentence.split()]
print(words)
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'one', "don't", '42', 'i', 'i', 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply using `split()`.

**No need to use regex** to extract words from list of strings:

```
word_list = []

for words in example:
    words = words.split()
    for word in words:
        word_list.append(word)

print(word_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['hi', 'one', "don't", '42', 'i', 'i', 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar', 'i']
```

Comment: This only returns unique items which is not what I want. I really appreciate the input though!

Comment: If you don’t want unique words simply use list instead of set (). That’s it. I thought you just want words, so duplicate didn't made sense.